# unexpected Chinese output from eclipse console

Tags: python, eclipse, utf-8

I attempted to change the character encoding to UTF-16 and it changed all of my text in Eclipse's text editor to Chinese. A ctrl-z saved my work, but now the console is stuck in Chinese.

When running an arbitrary python script, the script terminates immediately and gives the following message: "†䙩汥•䌺屄敶屗..." (The string goes on for much longer, but stackoverflow detects it as spam)

What does this mean? I've tried resetting things to default but to no avail.

Comment: Can't tell; the message starts with `File "C:\Dev\W` when I encode to UTF-16 big-endian, then decode as UTF-8, but there are not enough 'bytes' to get more than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit -> Set encoding UTF-16 screwed up my text again. another ctrl-z and Edit->set encoding ASCII fixed it.